# How to save additional/extra columns of the polymorphic morphable model in Laravel (7)?

Tags: php, database, laravel, many-to-many, polymorphic-relationship

Take a many-to-many polymorphic relationship sample from the Laravel docs website.

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

videos
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
    extra_column_a - string
    extra_column_b - integer
```

How to insert data into the `extra_column_a` and `extra_column_b` column when creating a post/video with tag or when creating a tag with post/video?

Do I need to create a model class for the `taggables` table when it has extra columns?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. Second parametr in arr

```
$video->tags()->attach($t, ['extra_column_a'=>'custstring','extra_column_b'=>'asd']);
```

Comment: Can I find it somewhere in the docs or do I have to dive into the base model class to discover such methods?

Comment: No, it's not mentioned in the docs. It's just like typically with many/many relations