# How to have multiple same polymorphic relations in one model in PHP-Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, relation

I'm dealing with a challenge where I want to create a polymorphic model **Localization**. This will include long-text columns like *default*, *en_us*, *de_de*,...

Now imagine another model **Product**. Products usually have text attributes like name, description,... Here comes the part, where I could use a polymorphic relation with *Localizations*. The *localizations* table is supposed to have this type of structure:

| id | localizable_id | localizable_type | default | en_us | de_de |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | App\Model\Product | Phone | *null* | Telefon |
| 2 | 25 | App\Model\Product | The best phone on the market without an audio jack | *null* | Das beste Telefon auf dem Markt ohne Audioanschluss |
| 3 | 15 | App\Model\Article | Top 10 products | *null* | Top 10 Produkte |
| 4 | 15 | App\Model\Job | Salesman | *null* | Verkäufer |

If I want a **Product** to have name and description localizable, then according to the Laravel documentation, you should expect something like this in my code:

```
class Product extends Model
{
  public function name() // Expecting model with default attribute 'Phone'
  {
    return $this->morphOne(Localization::class,'localizable');
  }

  public function description() // Expecting model with default attribute 'The best phone on the market without an audio jack'
  {
    return $this->morphOne(Localization::class,'localizable');
  }
}
```

No matter how obvious it is, it won't work correctly, because I can't expect two identical methods to return different values.

On the other side, if I wanted to follow Laravel's convention, the *Localization* model is supposed to look like this:

```
class Localizable extends Model
{
  public function localizable()
  {
    return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__,'localizable_type','localizable_id');
  }
}
```

As you can see in the example above, the polymorphic relation is inverse to what I need. The problem is that I want one table with all the strings, which might be translated (*localizables*) and use them in many other models than just the **Product**, like **Shop**, **Job**, **Article**,...

I need to somehow implement the distinction not only between localizable_types but also on which column/attribute it is supposed to be related. What is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Why not use Laravel's built-in localization support? If you want to be able to edit the translation files via web interface, there are packages like this one. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager

Comment: @miken32 first I need to be able to create specific packages for translating agencies (which is not possible via laravel’s localizations). Second I need to separate app localization from data localization. Third it does not answer the question in general - another example might be applied to images, where one user can have a profile image and a background image (with polymorphic images for use in e.g. articles)

Comment: Wouldn't simply adding another column to the table with the type (name, description, etc.) work? Then filter the relationship based on it?

Comment: @miken32 I thought of column localizations.localizable_context which would work for retrieving existing records, but I would have to somehow modify the Localization’s save() method to add this relation name to it. And I don’t how to access such information from the save method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610956/how-to-save-additional-extra-columns-of-the-polymorphic-morphable-model-in-larav

Comment: @miken32 that is not the answer. I have 1:1 relation, which is not that much of a difference. But more importantly, this approach would require to explicitly specify the relation type for every new instance - that seems to be prone to bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a workaround that fulfills my expectations. Even though it is not the most beautiful (or *Laravel*) way to do it. I got inspired from a similar struggle that I've found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/2061).

The point of this solution is to override **Product**'s `getMorphClass()` method that is being used to determine the `*_type` column value. My **Product** model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
  protected $morphClass = null; // Create an attribute that will not be saved into the DB
  public function getMorphClass() // Method for determinating the type value
  {
    return $this->morphClass? : self::class;
  }

  public function name()
  {
    $this->morphClass = self::class . '.name'; // App\Models\Product.name
    return $this->morphOne(Localization::class, 'localizable');
  }

  public function description()
  {
    $this->morphClass = self::class . '.description'; // App\Models\Product.description
    return $this->morphOne(Localization::class, 'description');
  }

}
```

The modification above will affect, how Laravel is going to save the **Localization**s to the database. Now, some work needs to be done from the other side of the relations - [custom polymorphic types](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types). Update your `AppServiceProvider` class in the `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file. You have to add morphMap to the `boot()` method:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
  // ...any of your previous modifications...

  Relation::morphMap([
    Product::class . '.name' => Product::class,
    Product::class . '.description' => Product::class,
  ]);
}
```

**BUT BE AWARE:** Once you decide to use multiple same-type morphs in your model, you have to change the protected attribute `$morphClass` in every dynamic method before calling `morphOne()` or `morphMany()`. Otherwise you might be saving descriptions to names or vice versa.

Also, when you will use the `morphTo()` method on the other side, you will only get the **Product** - if you need to know, what attribute on the **Product** model is being related on, I recommend you to create some method for extracting the context.

Please feel free to comment any potential threats in this approach.